# Decode CID from Inline MailItem.Attachment

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office-interop, mailitem

Struggling hard since a while with this problem:

I'm using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook interface
to extract Data from Outlook Mailitems.. the problem is, I need to decode the CID of Inline Attachments in the Mailitem.HtmlBody..but seems like it isn't Base64 encoded
Can you guys give me a hint how I could extract the readable filename out of this CID?

```
<img border=0 width=21 height=23 id="_x0000_i1026" src="cid:_4_0E370FF00E3701A80042B44CC12585CA">
```

I'd be very thankful for any ideas from you ☺

Comment: I'm pretty sure the CID is just an identifier. It doesn't otherwise encode any meaningful data. You need to find the attachment with that CID and extract the details you're looking for from that.

Comment: Oh dang..well I'm downloading the attachments via Mailitem.Attachments and store them temporarily local..even the Inline Attachments are downloaded with the correct name for example Att0001.png But I need to find out what Cid is referring to what file...

Comment: Solved it with Attachment.PropertyAccessor GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F") Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. You might want to add that as an answer to your own question for future visitors.

Comment: I will do so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by getting the Cid with:
Attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F")